# Right way to customize bootstrap container width as well the columns

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a XD design which width is **1152px**. There are 2 column on the XD design.

**Left column width is : 794px

Right Column width is : 300px

Between this 2 column there are 58px gap.**

Now, I am using Bootstrap 4 to design the HTML part.

I am very confused where I should change the container width as well as columns width OR what is right solution to make the HTML part as the XD design width?

Answer (score 1):

The overall container size could be changed in the _variables.scss file of Bootstrap here:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss#L307

```
$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
) !default;
```

Of course you can change the xl value to your 1152px.

The grid gutter width can be set n the same file here:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss#L322

Default is:
    $grid-gutter-width:           30px !default;

Change it to 58px

BUT the left and right column must be a fraction of 12 = 1/12, 2/12, 3/12 etc..
So you can use this markup:

```
    <div class="col-8">729px</div>
    <div class="col-4">365px</div>
```

or

```
    <div class="col-9">820px</div>
    <div class="col-3">274px</div>
```

But in both cases you can´t have the exact pixelperfect value.

The problem is that 794px of 1152px is 68,9236111%. A very strange way to calculate the size of an col. By default the XD designer should use 2/3 or even 66,67% (which is `class="col-8"` in Bootstrap, it means "take 8/12 of the size" ... which is equal to 2/3).

So in case it helps: Blame the designer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap doesn't go like that if you have a design specifically made for bootstrap then it must be designed according to 12 columns structure. All the designs of websites that I have converted for bootstrap were all structured as 12 columns 
Here you can find XD resources for bootstrap and it will be easier to convert the template

> xdresources.co/resources/bootstrap-4-ui

Comment: Okay. let me check it